# panel hide and show in NGUI

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine, ngui

I am new to `NGUI` and `unity 3d`.
  I have two panels in a `ui` root. its named as `firstPanel` and `secondPanel`. secondPanel is deactivated in scene. In `firstPanel` i have so many buttons and one is a `play` button, that is image button. While Clicking on `play` button, `firstPanel` should get **hide** and `secondPanel` should **show**.I adde a new Script to `play` button and written code in it

```
void OnClick(){
    GameObject panel2  = GameObject.Find("secondPanel");
    NGUITools.SetActive(panel2,true);       
    GameObject panel1  = GameObject.Find("firstPanel");         
    NGUITools.SetActive(panel1,false);

}
```

But I  get this **Error** : `"NullReferenceException"`
 In which script of `ngui` i have to edit and how can i do it? please help me to solve this issue
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which line do you get the exception?

Comment: GameObject panel2  = GameObject.Find("secondPanel"); here i am getting error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your panels are named as Panel1 and Panel2, you will not find them by using GameObject.Find("secondPanel") and GameObject.Find("firstPanel"). If "Panel1" and "Panel2" is the only name in the game scene(No other Panel1 or Panel2), then you can try to use

```
void OnClick(){
  GameObject panel2  = GameObject.Find("Panel2");
  NGUITools.SetActive(panel2,true);       
  GameObject panel1  = GameObject.Find("Panel1");         
  NGUITools.SetActive(panel1,false);

}
```

Comment: sorry. its not working properly. secondpanel is inactive in scene. so i cant able show it.

Comment: So I think keep them as reference will work. Try this:

Add "public GameObject panel2;" in your script(in the class body, for example just above the void OnClick). Then select your play button, you will see a field called "Panel2" on your script in the Inspector. Drag the secondPanel from game scene to the field. Then you can delete the GameObject line and use panel2 directly.

Comment: Why use GameObject.Find and NGUITools.SetActive? That's so slow... 
Isn't there a way to just not render?

Answer (score 3):

GameObject.Find("Something") cannot find any disabled game object, so you cannot use by this way. You can try to add reflection to your button code:

```
public GameObject pannel1 = null;
public GameObject pannel2 = null;
```

and set them to right panel in the scene editor window.

Another way, first you need to keep both of your panels active in your scene, then add code to your button script like this:

```
private GameObject panel1 = null;
private GameObject panel2 = null;
void Start()
{
    panel1 = GameObject.Find("Panel1");
    panel2 = GameObject.Find("Panel2");
}

void OnClick()
{
    panel2.SetActiveRecursively(true);
    panel1.SetActiveRecursively(false);
}
```

GameObject.Find(string name) function is not very efficient in Unity3D, so do not try to use it in Update() or every time you click your button.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old but if anyone else is having an issue calling panels when they are inactive you can prefab your panel and use the NGUITools.AddChild to call your panel.  It would look something like this.

```
public GameObject parent;
public GameObject child;

void Spawn () {

NGUITools.AddChild (parent, child);

}
```

Assign your UIRoot to parent (or whatever you want to add the panel to), and assign your panel to child in the editor and you're all set!  I hope this helps someone out, this is a common problem when first working with NGUI.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use GameObject.Find() to find a disabled gameobject, it's return null;